# srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 - get dropbox share link on a Laravel 5.3 application

Tags: laravel-5.3, dropbox

I am using srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 package with a Laravel 5.3 installation. My files are getting stored in dropbox however I'm not able to retrieve the shareable link of these dropbox files. Also, I want that the link should be visible to guest users too. Does anyone know how to go about this?

I have tried this, but this results in a file download whereas I need the shareable link for guest users.

```
$project_report_name = 'testdoc.docx'; //file saved in storage
$dropbox_client = new DropboxClient(env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'));
dd($dropbox_client->getTemporaryLink($project_report_name));
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/srmklive-flysystem-dropbox-v2-get-dropbox-share-link/m-p/229345#M12455 ]

Comment: My problem was solved by using both the packages together i.e.
https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox & https://github.com/spatie/dropbox-api
 
For anyone else who has similar requirements, the above 2 packages are supported for PHP 7, however for PHP 5 you'll have to use https://github.com/srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2